# How to share a URL to linkedIn via iOS app

Tags: ios, linkedin-api

In a iOS app I need to share url to LinkedIn via iOS app and LinkedIn native app is not installed in the device.I need to share url without th LinkedIn app installed 
Please guide me how cabn I do the same

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the different options are detailed under:
https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/share-on-linkedin

## via opening SAFARI

just call a customized URL with `openURL:`.

the format of the url is described by the linkedIn Developer Docs:

example:

```
https://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&url=http://developer.linkedin.com&title=LinkedIn%20Developer%20Network&summary=My%20favorite%20developer%20program&source=LinkedIn
```

---

## via REST API

e.g. call via `NSURLSession`

```
https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/shares?format=json
```

and pass JSON body

e.g.

```
{
  "comment": "Check out developer.linkedin.com! http://linkd.in/1FC2PyG",
  "visibility": {
    "code": "anyone"
  }
}
```

Note that with the REST API, you need to register your app with linkedin (all described in the docs)

Comment: thanks for your answer this helped me a lot please solve one more query that will be great help, if the app is installed then how to do the same.